# Scrolling on iframe without scrolling whole webpage

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm in the process of developing a website which uses the layout of having the navigation `iframe` on the left, and the content `iframe` in the middle. Given that some of the pages which will display in the content `iframe` have significantly less text than others, I don't want to just have some arbitrarily large height value for my content `iframe` as that will result in unnecessarily large amounts of whitespace for most pages.

Ideally, I should be able to scroll on the content `iframe` while leaving the rest of the webpage in place, and I should be able to scroll only as far as there is content on the currently loaded page in the content `iframe` (maybe plus 25 pixels or so just for some nice padding).

Currently, the code for the content `iframe` is as follows:

`<iframe name="content" src="content.html" style="height:2500px; width:1500px; border:none; position:absolute; top:215px; left:205px; scrolling:yes; overflow-y:scroll;" title="Content Pane"></iframe>`

I want to avoid JavaScript if at all possible. I've went on probably a dozen different websites now to no avail, but this seems like it should be a simple problem to solve.

Comment: Why are you using an iframe to do this?

Comment: @LeeTaylor If I want to embed a webpage within another webpage, this is the only way I know how to do it. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Using an iframe for navigation is not a common approach in modern web development. I'm not saying it's wrong, it's just unusual. You don't need to embed a webpage in another. Please explain what you are actually trying to achieve, rather than the problems you are having with your proposed solution.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I want a setup a bit similar to StackOverflow's insofar as I can scroll the main content part of the page (i.e. the question asked on StackOverflow) while the navigation pane on the left stays fixed in place, and the range of the scrolling should always fully cover the content with only a small amount of padding at the bottom irrespective of how much content is actually on the page.

Comment: OK. SO does not use iframes for it's navigation. I suggest you look at how they've done it.

Comment: @LeeTaylor While that sounds like a great suggestion, SO has a lot of formatting to its web design that I need to sort through in order to understand what the simple underlying structure is that I need to apply to my own website. It would seem like the more simple answer would just be to explain "in order to have part of the webpage scroll and part of it not scroll, instead of using iframes, use X". Then I can research X without having to spend hours trying to dissect a modern website's code.

Comment: The fundamentals are use divs. The left menu uses `position:sticky`. Overflow is controlled using `overflow` (to allow for scrolling. It's height is controlled using css calculations `calc` and `var(--top-bar-allocated-space);`

Comment: You would be wise to learn how to use your browser's developer tools. They will help you to analyse how SO's pages are constructed.